# Retrieve value from database and Serialize into json

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

The request json looks like this:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "generic": {
        "key1":"string-type-value1"
        "key2":"string-type-value2"
        "key3":"complex-type-value3"
        .
        ..
        ...
        "keyn": "simple/complex-valuen"
    }
}
```

The value of "**generic**" attribute above is a complex json.

I'm able to persist the entire complex json in a database column (by deserializing the json into a byte array and then persisting the value in the database as a blob type column).
However, when I try to retrieve the data again from the database, it's giving me a JSON string instead of a complex json

How can I re-create the exact complex json back from database using Jackson library?

I don't need a string representation of the json, but I need the original json back.

Answer (score 0):

Would a [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) instance be fine?

```
final String json = "" +
        "{" +
        "    \"key1\": \"value1\"," +
        "    \"generic\": {" +
        "        \"key1\":\"string-type-value1\"," +
        "        \"key2\":\"string-type-value2\"," +
        "        \"key3\":\"complex-type-value3\"," +
        "        \"keyn\": \"simple/complex-valuen\"" +
        "    }" +
        "}";

final JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(json, JsonNode.class);
System.out.println(node.get("generic").get("key1")); // "string-type-value1"
```

Comment: Hi...That is not what I'm looking for.
I get the byte array from the database and my requirement is to create the original complex json from bytearray.

Comment: @Sandy: Like `final String json = new String(byteArray);`?

Comment: Yes similar to this....but I don't want it to cast to a String.

final String json = new String(byteArray);

will give me a string representation of the json,which I dont want.

Comment: Well... it's gonna be either a `String`, a generic `JsonNode`... or a `Map<String, Object>`. Or a custom class representing your actual data! What exactly do you want to use?

Comment: basically we receive the blob from the database and we save it into a bytearray.After serialization, the final output should look like this:

`"generic": {
        "key1":"string-type-value1"
        "key2":"string-type-value2"
        "key3":"complex-type-value3"
        .
        ..
        ...
        "keyn": "simple/complex-valuen"
    }`

Comment: `mapper.readValue(byteArray, JsonNode.class).get("generic").toString()` is exactly `== "generic": { "key1":"string-type-value1", "key2":"string-type-value2", "key3":"complex-type-value3" . .. ... "keyn": "simple/complex-valuen" }`